# How to use AT&T Beam USB Modem under Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I'm trying to use AT&T Beam USB Modem (AC340U) on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Raspberry Pi Model B+. On both systems I can see eth1 connection being present but I'm not able to use it. In Ubuntu eth1 is shown in ifconfig output and there is a corresponding connection in the GUI connection manager, but I'm not able to activate it because the menu item for connecting it is gray and it says "device not managed". In raspberry pi I also see the eth1 in ifconfig. Can anyone help me?

I tried the following. The steps marked with (*) are listed in [the official guide](http://support.netgear.com/product/AirCard%2B340U%2B$28AT$26T$29).

On a Windows 7 computer:

1. (*) Plugged in the device, installed the driver, updated the firmware to version 01.13.12.13.
2. (*) Applied the patch to disable the Windows 8 MBIM functionality. The link to the patch is not available anymore so I searched it and installed it from [here](http://filemare.com/en-us/browse/174.35.24.133/pub/netgear/files/aircard/AC340U_linux_patch_v4-removed.zip). Not sure if this is the correct thing to do.

On Raspberry Pi B+:

1. There is initially no linux-headers package which is needed in the installation, so I followed [this post](http://forum.stellarisiti.com/topic/1748-howto-get-the-raspian-kernel-installed-with-working-headers/) to install it, which is successful and the kernel in use after the installation was 3.12-1-rpi.

On both Ubuntu 14.04 and Raspberry Pi B+:

(the kernel version of Ubuntu was 3.13.0-35-generic)

1. (*) sudo make all/install the GobiNet and GobiSerial, which are successful.

After that, my ifconfig on Ubuntu is like the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:88:88:88:87:88  
          inet addr:192.168.1.183  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8a88:88ff:fe88:8788/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:73 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11457 (11.4 KB)  TX bytes:21763 (21.7 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f9100000-f9120000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9e:90:32:a1:01:08  
          UP BROADCAST NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

However I don't know how to use this connection "eth1".

I tried `sudo dhclient -r eth1` and `sudo ifconfig eth1 up`. Neither has any effect.

The connection is disabled in the drop down menu (the connection named Sierra Wireless AirCard 340U):

[image]

And I have two connections in the connection manager:

[image]

I also checked the boot log and the GobiNet is loaded:

```
louis@louis-shao-rig:~$ dmesg | grep Gobi
[   76.715756] GobiNet: 2013-10-08/NTGR_2.21
[   76.717909] GobiNet 7-2:1.8 eth1: register 'GobiNet' at usb-0000:08:00.0-2, GobiNet Ethernet Device, 9e:90:32:a1:ab:48
[   78.128534] usbcore: registered new interface driver GobiNet
[   78.129664] usbcore: registered new interface driver GobiSerial
[   78.129698] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GobiSerial
[   78.129725] GobiSerial: 2013-10-08/NTGR_2.12:GobiSerial
```

What I observed in Raspberry Pi B+ is similar except that the GUI part is not applicable there.

I found several posts from the internet. For example, [this post](http://wes.skeweredrook.com/raspberry-pi-att-beam/) resolves a problem until one can see GobiNet being loaded. I didn't try this approach since I can see the same output (the boot log above). Also [this post](http://mtekk.us/archives/guides/netgear-aircard-340u-linux/) but I'm not sure whether what I did is the same.

UPDATE:

After the installation the official guide says to use `sudo ifconfig eth1 up` to bring up the interface. However I already had the interface. It says I can manually connect by sending the AT commands to /dev/ttyUSB2. I don't know how to do this and the following is what I tried:

1. `sudo apt-get install minicom`
2. `minicom -s`
3. It pops up a menu and I selected "Serial port setup", and set "Serial Device" to "/dev/ttyUSB2".
4. Select "Exit" in the main menu.
5. It enters a screen with the following message and whatever I type there is no effect.

   Welcome to minicom 2.7

   OPTIONS: I18n
   Compiled on Jan  1 2014, 17:13:19.
   Port /dev/ttyUSB2, 21:09:36

   Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

Answer (score 1):

On my Raspberry Pi 3 I found there was a conflict between the `GobiNet` and `qmi_wwan` drivers. Disabling the `qmi_wwan` driver (with `sudo rmmod qmi_wwan` followed by a fresh `sudo modprobe GobiNet`) and adding a `blacklist qmi_wwan` line to `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` resolved the conflict. Now the interface comes up as `eth1` every time and works perfectly on startup with DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do much with Network Manager if you used the last instruction on your third link.  And being a mobile broadband connection, you'll want to let Network Manager try to configure for you, seeing how helpful that serial connection is. =P NM on the Pi? awesome.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain a little more why NM is not useable after installing linux-headers on pi?

Comment: You're headers are probably fine.  The modules built, and the drivers are loaded.  There are a many ways that modern linux systems can configure network devices and connections.  NetworkManager is way more user-friendly and configurable than the lower-level methods that are still there.  The installation procedure for your modem drivers involved adding to the configuration file for the Ifup-down programs, and by default, NM is set ignore any connections defined there.

Comment: Comment out the corresponding lines in the file '/etc/network/interfaces' with '#' marks to let NetworkManager do what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the AC340U supports directly writing to a serial port, as the Netgear / Sierra Wireless drivers are pre 3.9 kernel. I have gotten the AC340U intermittently recognized as `eth1` (versus `wwan0`) about 30% of the time on power up on a 3.12.35+ `raspbian`.  I'm not sure why it sometimes is registered as `wwan0` instead of `eth1`.  Nonetheless, if you set **IP pass-through** mode and **autoconnect** (2 utilities that you can find on the web), then the AC340 should connect to the default APN and give you an IP (if you set `dhcp` for the `eth1` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Let me know if that helps, or if you have already figured it out, please let me know how you figured it out and what worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've gotten mine to work is right here:
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=185124

Ubuntu 14.10 - Sierra 340u (AT&T Beam)

Comment: Not always wise just to rely on a link to answer a question as links sometimes become inactive rendering your answer useless. Best to précis the relevant points in your link to support your answer.